# problems loading lme4 from github

Tags: macos, github, lme4

I am trying to load the developmental version of lme4 from github, and thus far have been unsuccessful. I am hoping that I might be able to steer me in the right direction.  Please bear with me as I am new to coding.

I am using Rstudio (Version 0.98.49) with R version 3.0.2, on a Mac with osX 10.9.  I installed the command line tools in the terminal using the call $xcode-select --install. I also downloaded MacTeX (although I am not sure this is necessary). I receive an error that the command failed, and am at loss for how to successfully load it.  Please see the code below.

```
>library(devtools)
> install_github("lme4",user="lme4",ref="release")
Installing github repo lme4/release from lme4
Downloading lme4.zip from https://github.com/lme4/lme4/archive/release.zip
Installing package from /var/folders/c1/m61j43qn3fs5xc43kg7s8jmh0000gn/T//Rtmp9PBWcN/lme4.zip
arguments 'minimized' and 'invisible' are for Windows only
Installing lme4
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --vanilla CMD build  \
  '/private/var/folders/c1/m61j43qn3fs5xc43kg7s8jmh0000gn/T/Rtmp9PBWcN/devtoolsb8344e5f03d/lme4-release'  \
  --no-manual --no-resave-data 

* checking for file '/private/var/folders/c1/m61j43qn3fs5xc43kg7s8jmh0000gn/T/Rtmp9PBWcN/devtoolsb8344e5f03d/lme4-release/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'lme4':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to build vignettes
      -----------------------------------
* installing *source* package 'lme4' ...
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c external.cpp -o external.o
external.cpp:340:18: warning: | has lower precedence than >; > will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
                         (isNAN(pdev) | pdev > oldpdev); k++) {
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
external.cpp:340:18: note: place parentheses around the '>' expression to silence this warning
                         (isNAN(pdev) | pdev > oldpdev); k++) {
                                      ^
                                        (             )
external.cpp:340:18: note: place parentheses around the | expression to evaluate it first
                         (isNAN(pdev) | pdev > oldpdev); k++) {
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
external.cpp:359:19: warning: | has lower precedence than >; > will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
                if (isNAN(pdev) | (pdev - oldpdev) > tol) 
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
external.cpp:359:19: note: place parentheses around the '>' expression to silence this warning
                if (isNAN(pdev) | (pdev - oldpdev) > tol) 
                                ^
                                  (                     )
external.cpp:359:19: note: place parentheses around the | expression to evaluate it first
                if (isNAN(pdev) | (pdev - oldpdev) > tol) 
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
2 warnings generated.
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c glmFamily.cpp -o glmFamily.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c mcmcsamp.cpp -o mcmcsamp.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c optimizer.cpp -o optimizer.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c predModule.cpp -o predModule.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c respModule.cpp -o respModule.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o lme4.so external.o glmFamily.o mcmcsamp.o optimizer.o predModule.o respModule.o /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/lib/libRcpp.a -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /private/var/folders/c1/m61j43qn3fs5xc43kg7s8jmh0000gn/T/RtmppWXl9s/Rinstd496922c9c0/lme4/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
   'PLSvGLS.Rnw' 
   'Theory.Rnw' 
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/c1/m61j43qn3fs5xc43kg7s8jmh0000gn/T/RtmppWXl9s/Rinstd496922c9c0/lme4/libs/lme4.so':
  dlopen(/private/var/folders/c1/m61j43qn3fs5xc43kg7s8jmh0000gn/T/RtmppWXl9s/Rinstd496922c9c0/lme4/libs/lme4.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN4Rcpp11EnvironmentixERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/c1/m61j43qn3fs5xc43kg7s8jmh0000gn/T/RtmppWXl9s/Rinstd496922c9c0/lme4/libs/lme4.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /private/var/folders/c1/m61j43qn3fs5xc43kg7s8jmh0000gn/T/RtmppWXl9s/Rinstd496922c9c0/lme4/libs/lme4.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing '/private/var/folders/c1/m61j43qn3fs5xc43kg7s8jmh0000gn/T/RtmppWXl9s/Rinstd496922c9c0/lme4'
      -----------------------------------
ERROR: package installation failed
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I'm sure that I am missing something obvious, but I appreciate any help as I continue to learn.  Thank you!

Comment: This is interesting.  I suspect you should try re-installing Rcpp (and other dependencies: RcppEigen, Matrix, minqa) first, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried reinstalling the dependencies and came up with the same output and error message. Any other suggestions?